# How can I generate a script of my database as it is?

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms

My primary reason for this is to keep track of database schema changes for my application.  In SQL Server Management Studio I am able to generate a create script which creates the database but it doesn't contain any test data.  Ideally when the script is run it should DROP the existing database (assuming it already exists) and then recreating it using this new script containing schema changes and test data from my development machine.

So how can I generate a script that will create a database with all the tables, stored procs, triggers, views, test data, etc?

I've tried using the import/export functionality but that's no good because it doesn't seem to copy over stored procedures.  Plus it would be nice to have a script so I can track changes to the schema using mercurial.

I am using SQL Server Express 2008 R2 along with SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: You can right-click on your database (on SQL Server management studio) and choose "generate scripts". There you can choose every aspect of the database that you want to script, including indexes, triggers, users, schemas and data (among things)

Comment: Maybe I am just being dense but I have tried that and there is no data at all in the file that is created.

Comment: you are presented with a lot of choices, one of them is to script the data (by default, this option is false)

Comment: @Lamak I see no such option.  On the second screen of the "wizard" I have two radio buttons, "Script entire database and all database objects" or "Select specific database objects" -> then I have a tree of the items in my database.  I don't see any explicit options for "data"...

Comment: Nevermind KD7's directions were spot on

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You didn't mention which version of SQL Server, but in SQL 2008 this is very easy

SQL 2008
 Expand Databases 
 Right Click Database
Choose Tasks > Generate Scripts
 Generate and
   Publish Dialog will open
 Choose your
   objects (i.e. Tables, procs, etc)
   Click Next On the Set Scripting
   Options choose Advanced Options
 Under
   General choose   SCRIPT DROP AND
   CREATE - SCRIPT DROP AND CREATE
    Types of Data To Script - Schema and
   Data 
Close Advanced Window
  Choose to
   save to file.

Comment: I'm kind of embarrassed that I couldn't find that.  Thanks so much though.

Comment: @Pete - I wouldn't be too embarrassed, as it's quite hidden! It's a useful feature that ought to be better surfaced in SSMS.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote an open source command line utility named [SchemaZen](https://github.com/sethreno/schemazen#schemazen---script-and-create-sql-server-objects-quickly) that does this. It's much faster than scripting from management studio and it's output is more version control friendly. It supports scripting both schema and data.

To generate scripts run:

```
schemazen.exe script --server localhost --database db --scriptDir c:\somedir
```

Then to recreate the database from scripts run:

```
schemazen.exe create --server localhost --database db --scriptDir c:\somedir
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [Microsoft SQL Server Database Publishing Wizard](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=56E5B1C5-BF17-42E0-A410-371A838E570A&displaylang=en).  This is a powerful flexible tool for scripting schema / data rom SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use [Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Database Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff678491.aspx) with a Source Control Repository (SVN) to track changes to the schema.

Answer (score 1):

Watch out for difference in database collation. If you develop on a database with a case insensitive collation and try and run the SSMS generated scripts against as database with a case sensitive collation then errors in case will break the scripts.

Answer (score -1):

Usually i make backups fom a database before start a new development on it.

the best way is restore the backup when needed, i don't know how to get it by the script way!