# Where did this invalid object name come from?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a simple SQL `UPDATE` query which is complaining about an "invalid object name" `AuditCrudFields` which doesn't exist in my ASP.NET project at all. (I have already tried grepping for `AuditCrudFields` in my project but couldn't find matches.)

The `UPDATE` statement is:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[PartModel]
SET partOfficial = 39, updateTS = CONVERT(DATETIME, ‘2017-12-08’, 111)  
WHERE partId = 298
```

the error returned:

[image]

What's puzzling is that these are all the properties that exist inside `PartModel`. So I wonder where did `AuditCrudFields` come from?

```
public class PartModel : EntityInformation
{
    [Key]
    public Int64 partId { get; set; }

    public int partTypeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("partTypeId")]
    public virtual PartTypeModel PartType { get; set; }

    public int locationId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("locationId")]
    public virtual LocationModel Location { get; set; }

    public int partOfficial { get; set; }
    public int partUnofficial { get; set; }
    public int partThreshold { get; set; }

    public string partImg { get; set; }
    public int partStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Probably from `EntityInformation`

Comment: Do you have any triggers in the database?

Comment: You will be glad to know that googling 'AuditCrudFields' reveals absolutely nothing...Surprising but comforting

Comment: Its possible that AuditCrudFields exists inside a Trigger or an Index..Sounds like a StoredProc name to me...(And that it has now been deleted or renamed, but still lingers inside a Trigger or Index definition)

Comment: This is 100% the result of a trigger failing.

Comment: It is not relevant with Entity Framework. Check the table triggers.

Comment: What happens when you remove updateTS from your UPDATE test query in SQL?

Comment: @Grantly When I removed `updateTS` from the `UPDATE` test query, I still got the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is a deleted or renamed object called `AuditCrudFields`  (I will call it a dead object)

This is probably inside a `Trigger` definition (or perhaps buried inside a Stored Procedure, Function or Index definition...)

The most effective way of finding a dead object is by scripting your entire database into text (into one big SQL Script), then search for the text...

Where you find the text, will point to where it is used (a Trigger perhaps), and then you can repair or remove the trigger and hopefully its fixed.

There is alot of help with scripting a SQL SERVER database on the internet or SO, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477117/how-can-i-generate-a-script-of-my-database-as-it-is) is another link

Comment: Very helpful answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can run this query to locate the SQL object code which is trying to use the table `AuditCrudFields`:

```
select *
from sys.objects
where object_definition(object_id) like '%AuditCrudFields%'
```

I'd be very surprised if this is not inside a trigger definition.

Comment: I ran the query, and this is what's returned: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6SlrTFyY_NjMzZ6WHNQWkNYOHc. Nothing. Hmm.

Comment: I don't have access to your Google Drive.  You're saying that query returns an empty result set?

Comment: I just made the image accessible. Sorry about that. Yes, returns an empty result set.

Comment: Also, on the Explorer menu, there were no triggers found: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6SlrTFyY_NjMzdLd3ZQUWI4Y0k

Comment: I'm looking inside the Views at the moment.

Comment: @Yuck would this show fields used in Indexes?  (Long shot though...Seems more like a SP name than a field name.  And its also difficult to have a lingering deleted field name in an Index too)

Comment: Here's the full stack trace when the error occurred: https://gist.github.com/sivabudh/3eec6d841db080634b8f1fadc39b38a6

Comment: @sivabudh look for triggers under dbo.PartModel table, not under "Server Objects"

Comment: I found this Stored procedure: https://gist.github.com/sivabudh/490facc9d2732e3379a5a7834278055a

Comment: Where there is smoke...there is fire :)

Comment: I would check Triggers under ALL the tables, as it could be a cascading trigger issue

Comment: Finally found it. There's a Trigger under the dbo.PartModel table. https://gist.github.com/b0bea724ade423eb243d4572461e4610

Comment: @Evk Thanks. I found the offending Trigger.

Comment: This query in the answer will only return VALID (current) object names, NOT deleted ones...  Try to script your entire database to a text file and then search for AuditCrudFields in the entire script...If you are using SQL Server this is quite easy

Comment: @sivabudh Strange that you marked this as answer, because it could not return anything - error clearly states that this object name is invalid, so - does not exists in your database.

Comment: @Grantly, I am using SQL Server. Would you point me to some resource that explains how to "script the database to a text file"? You mean dump the whole database as a .SQL file?

Comment: Sure, here is the easiest way... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477117/how-can-i-generate-a-script-of-my-database-as-it-is

Comment: If you don't actually need to RUN the script, then its easy - just use trial and error with some techniques in link above

Comment: @sivabudh You are welcome, I will post this stuff as an Answer for anyone who has the similar problem in the future